# Is it possible to schedule a DeviceJob Twin update on a edge device module via Java sdk?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

We are trying to schedule a Edge Device module twin update but I'm not sure if that's supported. I am able to query for the twin via tha azure query explorer. We are currently using this to schedule a twin update for a device, I would assume that using the queryCondition of "deviceId=device AND moduleId=module" would schedule a twin update for `device.module`. It doesn't seem to work and I'm wondering if it's because the default FROM clause targets "devices" instead of "devices.modules".

```
jobClient.scheduleUpdateTwin(jobId, queryCondition, deviceTwinDevice,
                    DateTime.now()).toDate(), Duration.ofMinutes(5).getSeconds());
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/tree/master/device/iot-device-samples and https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java see if it helps.

Comment: You sent me the examples from the device sdk; the job samples are in the service sdk here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/master/service/iot-service-samples/job-client-sample/

Also, there are no samples of scheduling a module twin job change; my guess is it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked the source code of the Java Azure IoT SDK. Currently the Job/Service function ['Update Module Twin'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/updatemoduletwin) is not supported or implemented.